# Is there a color picker plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm using Eclipse Galileo PDT for my work. I also use it to edit my CSS files.

Is there a plugin that lets me pick a color (from a palette or even anywhere from the screen) and which returns the HEX value of that color into my CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aptana Studio has really great support for CSS.  CSS color picking is easy, you can grab a color from anywhere on the screen.

You can install Aptana as a plug into an existing Eclipse installation.
http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration

[image]

Comment: This answer and screenshot applied to Aptana Studio 2. In Studio 3 the color picker is no longer accessible from the toolbar. Instead one should use Commands > CSS > Insert Color...

Comment: Are there such tools but not from Aptana? Aptana is horrible

Comment: so disappointing that the asker choose this answer.  installing Aptana to have a color picker is like swatting a mosquito with a tactical nuke.  Jspresso is a much better option

Comment: This answer is from 2010, I hope people aren't still using this answer for guidance! I'd recommend now just switching to IntelliJ ;)

Answer (score 5):

[Jspresso Colors 'n Fonts](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jspresso-colors-n-fonts)

> Just select any java string literal and right click on it to open the contextual popup menu... then select Jspresso>Choose Color... or select Jspresso>Choose Font...
>
> Supports also tooltip : fly over your string literal to display the current color or font... and activate hyperlink to open the editor popup !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few plugins at the [Eclipse plugins site](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/search.jsp?query=color) that might meet your needs.

[CSS Designer](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=1419) looks promising:

> JointLogic CSS Designer is an Eclipse plugin that provides CSS authoring facilities like - CSS Styles view, CSS declaration designer with preview and web-oriented color picker. It integrates with Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) to allow CSS authoring while editing CSS and HTML files.

Here's a screesnhot from the [homepage](http://www.jointlogic.com/cssdesigner/):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is nice, BUT: It does not integrate with the editor window, wich really is a pity. When I'm typing in the editor and want to change a color, then I must search the CSS rule in the CSS Designer window to change the attribute. It would be much more intuitive if the cirrently "selected" rule in the editor is highlighted in the Designer window.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use external software: http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html
You can integrate it into Eclipse.

Comment: There is a "Run" submenu in Eclipse you can customize. But, probably, CSS Designer http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugin%5Fdetails.jsp?id=1419 recommended by Rich Seller will suit you better.

Comment: The point is, CSS Designer does not suite me better as commented above. I'll have a look at the "run" menu. Whereas my wish is a context menu ...

Answer (score 1):

I have used this plugin called colors in both Galymeade and I just dropped into Galileo.
http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-1281.html  you can copy the color code to/from clipboard or editor. Slider bar for coloring, color picker etc. I used it to edit css files on a recent project.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the second example at http://eclipsescript.org/#example-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [Groovy Monkey](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Monkey) script that opens Eclipse's color picker. It was inspired by what fornwall pointed at ([second example of Eclipse Script plugin](http://eclipsescript.org/#example-scripts)). It's also able to recognize if current selection is a color so it can be selected it in the picker.

The script is on [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/931936), instructions included.

Having a [shortcut key for a script is not (yet?) possible](http://sourceforge.net/projects/groovy-monkey/forums/forum/575323/topic/2243757) in Groovy Monkey, but Crtl+Alt+M runs the last executed script.

Answer (score 1):

A good plugin to consider is the Designerator Color Plugin from the [Designerator](http://www.designerator.org) project. It contributes a Colors view as explained in this [blog post](http://designeratorblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/color-and-gradient-for-eclipse.html). No need to install the whole software, the color view is in a separate feature that can be installed by itself.

The [Sampler plugin](http://code.google.com/p/sandipchitaleseclipseplugins/#Sampler_Plug-in) could also be of interest. However it does not show a color picker dialog where one can select a color, it only has the color picker tool for selecting a color from the screen.