# Color picker in Flash builder 4 for actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, flash-builder

Is there a  color picker for actionscript in Flash Builder 4? 
It is very annoying to create custom components in actionscript without being able to get color codes in from Flash builder itself.

As of right now I have to get color codes from the internet or Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Flash Builder is built on Eclipse, you might find answers here: [Is there a color picker plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471546/is-there-a-color-picker-plugin-for-eclipse)