# Eclipse RCP color picker

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In the Eclipse preferences there is a color picker control in every Syntax highlighting preferences page. It consists of a colored button

[image: colour select button]

that opens a dialog

[image: color picker dialog]

I want to use this components in my RCP application but I can't find out which they are or if they are even available.

I'm guessing the button might be a normal button. This would be easy to build myself. But I want to avoid building the whole dialog myself.

Can anyone tell me where to find this component?

PS: I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471546/is-there-a-color-picker-plugin-for-eclipse) but it doesn't offer a "native" Eclipse solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stumbled upon it myself now (while looking for something entirely different). It is the `org.eclipse.jface.preference.ColorFieldEditor`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can directly use org.eclipse.jface.preference.ColorSelector class to use.
following is the snippet on how to use.

```
final ColorSelector colorSelector = new ColorSelector(shell);
        colorSelector.getButton().addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                System.out.println(" selected color :: "
                        + colorSelector.getColorValue());

            }
            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```