# how to create a color palette inside a composite (swt)

Tags: java, swt, swt-awt

i want to add a color palette inside a composite (swt).
there is ColorPalette class but i don't know how to use it inside my composite.

it will be inside eclipse view plugin

Comment: Do you mean something like a [ColorDialog](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratestheColorDialogclass.htm)?

Comment: Not exactly, I was looking for the color palette more like taht: http://www.appszoom.com/android_applications/tools/color-palette_bhhmu.html

but the color dialog seem to be fine as well, so thank you!

Comment: is it possible to show it in my composite and not as a pop up?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here:

1.Use [`ColorDialog`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratestheColorDialogclass.htm) which looks like this:

[image]

2.Have a look ath [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256694/eclipse-rcp-color-picker) related question which seems to be what you are searching for. It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used sub classes of following class from Windows Builder Core when i was working on Custom designer tool.

http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.windowbuilder/trunk/org.eclipse.wb.core/src/org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/ui/dialogs/color/AbstractColorsGridComposite.java

This might help you to figure out solution to your problem.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows Builder for Eclipse. Hopefully, this code can be useful.

```
    //  COLOR PALETTE
    {
        JColorChooser tcc = new JColorChooser();
        getContentPane().add(tcc, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
    }
```

I used this code inside a JDialog window. The result was this:

[image]

Place the code snippet inside the JDialog constructor, after the initial code that setups the window.