# Eclipse Color Picker Plugin for XML files

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, color-picker

There is a similar question about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471546/is-there-a-color-picker-plugin-for-eclipse). But it is for CSS. I want to pick colors in XML file while working on an Android Project. Is there a plugin for this purpose?
I researched about 2-3 hours for this but I could not reach anything?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a plugin specifically for Android XML editing, and the ADT team doesn't seem to be keen on adding this feature in the near future.  However, using any color picker that produces HEX (html) style color codes should work.

[This plugin](http://milanl.wz.cz/eclipse/colors/) looks promising.  Should allow you to open the color picker, select a color using a system color selection or by sampling pixels on the screen and copy the HEX code to the clipboard or insert it directly into your source code.